# Store mysql column to array PHP

Tags: php

I use this to get a column named "device_token" and save the values to an array:

```
mysql_connect("localhost", "xxxx", "xxxx") or die ("Not connected");
mysql_select_db("xxxxx") or die ("no database");
$query = "SELECT xxxx_device_token FROM device_tokens";


$result_array = array();
while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result))
{
    $result_array[] = $row['xxxx_device_token'];
}
print_r($result_array);
```

But all I get is an empty array, what is the problem ?

Comment: That there are no results...

Comment: Are you sure, your query returns any value?

Comment: You missed the `$result = mysql_query($query)`.

Comment: your $query is just a string, you have no mysql_query, neither assigned $result

Answer (score 2, accepted):

your code is not correct,
try like  this

```
mysql_connect("localhost", "xxxx", "xxxx") or die ("Not connected");
mysql_select_db("xxxxx") or die ("no database");
$query = "SELECT xxxx_device_token FROM device_tokens";
$result = mysql_query($query);


$result_array = array();
while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result))
{
    $result_array[] = $row['xxxx_device_token'];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

$result is empty and $query is not used anywhere.

You need something like this:

```
$result = mysql_query($query);
```

http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-query.php

Answer (score 0):

Your code is not correct. You didn't execute the query. You need to do this :

```
mysql_connect("localhost", "xxxx", "xxxx") or die ("Not connected");
mysql_select_db("xxxxx") or die ("no database");

$result_array = array();
$query = mysql_query("SELECT xxxx_device_token FROM device_tokens");

while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($query))
{
    $result_array[] = $row['xxxx_device_token'];
}
print_r($result_array);
```

But `mysql_query` is deprecated in new verion of PHP, so you need to do this with `mysqli_query`.

Answer (score 0):

Try this,

```
$query = "SELECT xxxx_device_token FROM device_tokens";
$result = mysql_query($query);


$result_array = array();
while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result))
{
    $result_array[] = $row['xxxx_device_token'];
}
```

Dont use Mysql functions. It is deprecated. Please move to Mysqli (or) PDO

Answer (score 0):

You have `mysql_fetch_assoc($result)` in the while statement, but no variable declaration for `$result`.

You must execute your query:

```
$result = mysql_query($query);
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming this is not a copy & paste error, you are probably missing this line:

```
$result = mysql_query($query);
```

Answer (score 0):

Try not to use `mysql_*`, it's not recommended, use `mysqli_*` , ideally you should be using [PDO](http://php.net/manual/en/book.pdo.php) for database connectivity.

That said you're missing this,
`$result = mysql_query($query);`

Answer (score 0):

You have forgotten to execute your MySQL query, like this:

`$result = mysql_query($con,"SELECT * FROM Persons");`